# How to make a rehash function for a hash table of vectors?

Tags: c++, hashtable

I have a hash table that is a vector of vectors of pairs.

```
std::vector <std::list<std::pair<K, V> > >  bucketVector;
```

How do I make a rehash function for something like this? Basically,m any time the number of elements in the table exceed the size of bucket vector, the vector needs to be resized

I have these helpers

```
unsigned long HashTable<K, V>::prime_below (unsigned long n)
{
    if (n > max_prime)
    {
        std::cerr << "** input too large for prime_below()\n";
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == max_prime)
    {
        return max_prime;
    }
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        std::cerr << "** input too small \n";
        return 0;
    }

    // now: 2 <= n < max_prime
    std::vector <unsigned long> v (n+1);
    setPrimes(v);
    while (n > 2)
    {
        if (v[n] == 1)
            return n;
        --n;
    }

    return 2;
}
```

However, I am not exactly sure how to, or if I even need to, add a rehash function.

```
//Sets all prime number indexes to 1. Called by method prime_below(n) 
    template <typename K, typename V>
void HashTable<K, V>::setPrimes(std::vector<unsigned long>& vprimes)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    vprimes[0] = 0;
    vprimes[1] = 0;
    int n = vprimes.capacity();

    for (i = 2; i < n; ++i)
        vprimes[i] = 1;

    for( i = 2; i*i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (vprimes[i] == 1)
            for(j = i + i ; j < n; j += i)
                vprimes[j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to be changing the values, and you're using the values to determine uniqueness, you really shouldn't be hashing them...

Comment: I agree, but my professor is requiring us to do it this way. I've come this far all I need is a rehash function but I cannot figure it out

Comment: What do you mean by rehash? If you're resizing the hash table, the hash values for all the elements should stay the same, just their position changes.

Comment: Okay, I'm not seeing anywhere here you're using hashes. What's this about a vector of vector of pairs?

Comment: bucketVector is the hash table. The rest of the code shouldnt matter right? It's just a matter of resizing a vector that's this complicated

Comment: If you're using the standard library resizing comes automatically? I still don't see what hashing has to do with this, and less so rehashing. Are you using bucketVector as a key in a hash table or something? And if so, do you have an original hash function?

Comment: Okay I've figured it out. Hashing isn't the issue, I really just had to resize the vector to a prime number and copy the old one over. I've implemented this and it works well